# Creating CSVT on Mac

Tags: qgis, csv, mac

I am working with QGIS on a Mac, and understand the process for importing a CSV file. However, I do not know how to create the CSVT file to define the CSV file's data types.

Can someone instruct me on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A CSVT file is just a plain text file that you create with the extension .csvt.  The file has a single line with the types for each column:

```
"Integer","Real","String"
```

Make sure there are no spaces between each `,` or type.

Comment: I just closed the question this answer is on thinking that CSVT would be a general IT rather than GIS/spatial format, but then did some searches to try and be sure of that and did not find anything conclusive.  If it should not be treated as a general IT format, can you let me know so that I can reverse my action?

Comment: @PolyGeo CSVT is an ogr thing in order to add types to csv. So best to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find a programme, where you can write the extention by hand. For windows you can do it in Gedit. First you type the line "Integer","real",... and so on, as it is written in previous answer and after clicking 'save as' you delete the given extention and type 'csvt'
for example programme gives 'fields.txt' then you delete 'txt' and write csvt instead to get 'fields.csvt'. Then you click save. It worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can either create the file in Excel (or similar) or a basic text editor using the correct format as noted above. Unfortunately Macs have a habit of adding .CSV or .TXT (depending on the software you use to create the file) after the .CSVT that you specified. In finder, right-click and select "`get info`" or use "`Command I`". in the window that pops up check the `Name & Extension` section. You may need to delete the .CSV or .TXT your application added after the .CSVT or simply change the extension to .CSVT. For example, I may have exported the CSVT file I created out of excel and specified the name as test.csvt but it was actually exported as test.csvt.csv (depending on your set-up the .csv at the end may be hidden). In `Finder` select the file, use `Command I` and under the `Name & Extension` remove the final .CSV to end up with test.csv
Hope this helps.